# Microsoft Internet Controls ieframe.dll or shdocvw.dll

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to run a report from a website out of Internet Explorer 11 using VBA. In the past I have used the Microsoft Internet Controls reference library, which gave me access to DOM members (getElementsByID, etc). In order to use those, I believe I need the shdocvw.dll, but when I select the Microsoft Internet Controls reference library, it is referencing the ieframe.dll.

Has anyone run into this? How can I create a reference to the shdocvw.dll?

I have tried going to "Browse" and select the shdocvw.dll to open. When I select open, nothing happens. Is there a different reference library that gives me access to DOM objects?

Comment: Did you try using the new reference - did that not work?

Comment: The reference never changed. I am looking for any reference library that references the shdocvw.dll, but can't find one. When I try to point the Microsoft Internet Controls reference to shdocvw.dll, it does not change.

Comment: I meant did you try using "Microsoft Internet Controls" *as is* without trying to repoint it to shdocvw.dll ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did. It does not allow me to use any of the "getElement" features I have used in the past. Basically you can reference the "Document" but it doesn't allow to do anything with it (that I can figure out).

Comment: For methods like `getElementsByXxxx` I think the reference you want is "Microsoft HTML Object library", not Internet Controls

Comment: Appreciate the info. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

XP Service pack 3 changes the file association for .URL. With service pack 2 installed .URL are associated with rundll32.exe shdocvw.dll,OpenURL %l, with service pack 3 shdocvw.dll is replaced with ieframe.dll