# VBA extract text value from webpage?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a webpage with some text in a HTML Span like so:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate">Expiry Date : 16/02/2018</span>
```

I am trying to get this value display it as a message in excel using the below code:

```
Sub PullExpiry()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.brcdirectory.com/InternalSite//Site.aspx?BrcSiteCode=" & Range("J6").Value
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop


Set getPrice = appIE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate")
Dim myValue As String
myValue = getPrice.innerText

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

MsgBox myValue
End Sub
```

This was working on my laptop (operating windows) but it does not work on my computer (also operating windows). Both windows are the same version with the same version of IE. I cannot explain it.

I have Microsoft Office and Excel Object libraries turned on in both references.

I get an error about an active x component not being able to create something

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: So it's bombing on `Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")`?

Comment: Can you provide a test value for Range("J6") which will return a non-empty webpage on that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Microsoft Internet Controls` to your references to be able to create the object. You may have to register the `shdocvw.dll` library on your computer. It may be registered on your laptop already which is why it might be bombing on your computer.

**[How to register a .dll](http://www.wikihow.com/Register-a-DLL)**

**[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx)**: look at the last sentence before the `C#` example.

**[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670975/microsoft-internet-controls-ieframe-dll-or-shdocvw-dll)**

After playing around a little bit and ensuring everything was registered, this ran fine on my PC:

```
Public Sub ie()

    Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set ieApp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium

    ieApp.Visible = True

    ieApp.Navigate "http://internalAddress/"

    Do While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ieApp.Document.getElementById("myID")

End Sub
```

Comment: I found a copy of `shdocvw.dll` here: `C:\Windows\System32`